# Trying to fix 3D mesh normals

Tags: algorithm, graphics, mesh, depth-first-search, normals

I have triangle collection that define mesh surface of my 3D shape,
I would like to fix normal of each triangle to point outshape.

I was trying the following (pseudo):

1. define that first triangle normal direction is right direction

 2. go over the mesh using kind of DFS like this:

 3. triangle = first triangle

 4. foreach neigbour in triangle.getNeighbours

 5. if angle between neighbor and triangle greater then 180 do neighbor.flip()

 6. triangle = neighbor 

 7. if neighbor already picked then continue to next neighbor 

 8. continue recursively to 4.

But step 5 in algorithm does not work because cant know if the angle is greater then 180, because i need to know in witch direction (clockwise or counter clockwise).

Could you please help me to understand how to fix the algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to calculate angle between neighbours. If triangle `ABC` is oriented (`A->B->C`), and if neighbour on edge `AB` is triangle `ABD`, than it has to have opposite orientation on edge `AB`. That means, neigbouring triangle has to be orientated `B->A->D`.

Comment: It is solving all the cases, something is wrong with this method, please visit my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036970/how-to-correct-winding-of-triangles-to-counter-clockwise-direction-of-a-3d-mesh and guide me what to do now... thanks.