# Is there one way to make the normals of one mesh consistent?

Tags: mesh, consistency, normals

Recently I get a triangle mesh, but the normal directions of triangles on the mesh is
not consistent. Is there any algorithm to convert the normals consistent?
From one book，it says 
*"Usually the orientation of the normals is propagated
along a minimum spanning tree between neighboring patches either in
a preprocessing step or implicitly during traversal of the input [Hoppe
et al. 92].*

Does it mean that making the normals consistent is not easy?

Regards
Jogging

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036970/how-to-correct-winding-of-triangles-to-counter-clockwise-direction-of-a-3d-mesh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easy business indeed. There are numerous papers on the subject. The original paper from which it all began is this:

H. Hoppe, T. DeRose, T. Duchamp, J. McDonald and W. Stuetzle, "Suface reconstruction from unorganized points," in SIGGRAPH, 1992. 
The method itself is realized in VCG (Meshlab) and PCL libraries.

One of the more recent papers:
J. Liu, J. Cao, X. Liu, J. Wang, X. Wang and X. Shi, "Mendable consistent orientation of point clouds," Computer-Aided Design, vol. 55, pp. 26-36, 2014 
http://jjcao.weebly.com/uploads/4/5/3/4/4534726/cad14.pdf

The authors of the paper provide a Matlab code: 
http://jjcao-orientation.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Code/
The code is much slower than the original Hoppe algorithm but gives much nicer results, especially in hard cases when the mesh contains sharp corners and non-smooth edges.

Also, a good review of general ideas is this one: http://vmv09.tu-bs.de/downloads/papers/koe09.pdf

If you know that the point cloud was obtained from a particular point (say, from a Kinect or a laser scanner), you can make the direction of the normals to be consistent with the viewpoint by flipping them if needed. But if you deal with a model of an entire object which, then some normal propagation algorithm is required.