# how to get correct triangle facing in dual contouring

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, mesh

As part of a procedural mesh generator, working on dual contouring to convert signed distance functions to meshes.

Hoping some folks with experience about the algorithm can help with this bit of it near the end.

We have

1. voxel grid edge cut-points and normals where the function surface crosses the edges

   a. we visit each corner of the grid, and project edges out along the x,y, and z axis

   b. each edge that exhibits a sign change in the function is deemed active
2. vertex points inside each voxel, calculated as the closest point of intersection of the planes defined by the cut-points and normals on the voxel edges

   a. we find each voxel to generate a vertex for by visiting each active edge

   b. wind around the edge in a counter-clockwise direction relative to the axis the edge is on.
3. generation of the mesh by winding around each active edge to connect the vertices inside of the 4 adjacent voxels into a quad.

When each face is generated, I must determine which way the face is facing so that the winding order is correct for the triangles making up the quad.

First we get the average normal for the each voxel vertex:

```
            float3 faceNormal = new float3(0f,0f,0f);
            float nCount = 0f;
            for (int eachVoxel = 0; eachVoxel < 4; eachVoxel++)
            {
                vid = edgeVoxels[eachVoxel];
                var theVoxel = _voxelsById[vid];

                faceNormal += theVoxel.VertexNormal.xyz;
                nCount += 1f;


            }

            faceNormal /= nCount;
            faceNormal /= faceNormal.Length();
```

Then we determine if we need to reverse the order:

```
            float faceAngle = float3.Dot(_axis[edge.EdgeDir], faceNormal);
            if (faceAngle > 0.0f)
            {
                distinctMeshVoxels = distinctMeshVoxels.Reverse();
            }
```

This almost works. Take this raymarched scene of an object:

[image: raymarched image]

Now here is the mesh imported into mesh lab. Notice the black triangle -- it's facing the wrong direction. Sharp edges seem to be a problem sometimes. I've tried various other approaches:
1. Averaging the edge cut-point normals, and 
2. Finding the cutpoint nearest to the triangle centroid and using it's normal,

Nothing is even as good as the image below.

[image: mesh with bad triangles]

Appreciate any advice or ideas on how to perfect this part of the algorithm.

Comment: It is more robust to orient faces topologically than geometrically. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216001/trying-to-fix-3d-mesh-normals).

Comment: Why do you average the vertex normals of a face? You already have the normal at the point where the surface intersects the edge. And one such edge generates one quad. Using this normal, orienting the quad should work flawlessly.

Comment: Nico, that is the simple, straight-forward method I suspected I was blind to. Best face palm moment ever ... will report results as soon as I can try it.

Comment: Yep, that was the right answer. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

In dual contouring one first detects the edges with a sign change, which are crossed by the reconstructed 3D surface. Each such edge produces a quad in the surface. The triangles constituting the quad are oriented so that the vertex of the edge with the positive value is located in the positive half-space relative the triangle and its normal.

Here is a simple tutorial of [dual contouring](https://www.boristhebrave.com/2018/04/15/dual-contouring-tutorial/) for more detail.